# Looking for advice on sprinkler system anti-siphon valve placement

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, valve, sprinkler-system, gardening

I'm looking to install my own sprinkler system in my backyard and I'd love some advice. Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do, a picture of a water valve (to be replaced by a T and a shut off valve) attached to my basement (house sits above this 8 ft) that would connect to a zoned controlled system: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ7gT.jpg

I'm planning on having [4 in-line zones](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rain-Bird-3-4-in-FPT-In-Line-Valve-CP075/202078357) powered by a [Battery-Operated Controller](https://www.plumbersstock.com/rainbird-esp9v4-f48344.html) in an irrigation box. 1 zone is flat with the space. 2 zones will have to make a journey 8 ft straight up to get to the side yards which are higher on the hill. The last zone goes into the backyard over 100ft, but 30 ft down various terraced areas.

Where would I need to put anti-siphon valves, if at all? Could I get away with a regular [anti-siphon valve](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rain-Bird-3-4-in-Anti-Siphon-Irrigation-Valve-with-Flow-Control-DASASVF075/100036021) instead or would the pressure mess it up? Seems like the latter is true since I have water going above the source. Or do I need [fancier vacuum breakers?](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Febco-Series-765-3-4-in-Bronze-NPT-Pressure-Vacuum-Breaker-765DBV/202309635) Any tips about this setup? It will be mostly PVC and breakout to Drip to water garden, trees, flowers.

EDIT: Here is a layout of the zones https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8iFS.jpg

Comment: What is the water source for this sprinkler system? Vacuum breakers, anti-siphon, etc are important when the sprinklers are sourced from a potable (drinking) water system, but if your system will use exclusively non-drinking/irrigation water then none of these are required.

Comment: Yes, water source is drinking water from the house. It starts at the top near the road/driveway, snakes all the way to the back of the house, goes down 8 ft to the basement where our laundry room is, goes across to the faucet in place at the lower ground level.